# How to play a sound every 2 seconds?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I want to know how to play a mp3 sound every 2 seconds.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flash.utils.Timer object to fire TimerEvents at whatever interval you like.  Another approach could be to add a 2 second gap to your mp3 and play it continuously.